# I need Awesomplete to preserve trailing spaces

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I have been using Awesomplete (a very nice autocomplete widget) for about two years. It works well, but apparently trims trailing spaces by default. I've been putting up with this, but I really need for trailing spaces to be preserved.

The list containing the needful trailing spaces is generated by a database; CSS has been applied to the webpage's input field to preserve trailing spaces -- however the spaces are still trimmed, so I think that Awesomplete is doing it.

I know very little Javascript, but I'm guessing that the relevant code is contained in what's below:

```
_.all = [];

_.FILTER_CONTAINS = function (text, input) {
    return RegExp($.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

_.FILTER_STARTSWITH = function (text, input) {
    return RegExp("^" + $.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "i").test(text);
};

_.ITEM = function (text, input, item_id) {
    var html = input.trim() === "" ? text : text.replace(RegExp($.regExpEscape(input.trim()), "gi"), "$&");
    return $.create("li", {
        innerHTML: html,
        "aria-selected": "false",
        "id": "awesomplete_list_" + this.count + "_item_" + item_id
    });
};

_.REPLACE = function (text) {
    this.input.value = text.value;
};

_.DATA = function (item/*, input*/) { return item; };
```

How can this be modified so that trailing spaces are preserved?

Thank you!

PS
I did not write the code quoted above; it is an excerpt of Awesomplete's JavaScript, containing what I thought was a relevant portion of their code. If in fact there is nothing there that trims trailing spaces, please tell me! Thx.

PS #2
It's not a dropdown box with "display" and "value". It's a text input field that autocompletes what the user types by pulling values from a list. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

`input.trim()` is what's trimming the white spaces, and it looks like they do it pretty often. However, that looks like it's mostly for display uses. You might want to try seeing if you can use the value with the spaces as the options "value" and allow the display text to be trimmed.